# Razor engine if else statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

Do I really have to mark each line with "@:" when I am evaluating a template with Razor Engine and just want to print the whole block contained inside of If statement:

```
@if(Model.Labels)
{
    @:arcs.append("text")
    @:.attr("transform", function (d) {
        @:var c = arc.centroid(d),
            @:x = c[0],
            @:y = c[1],
            @:// pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
            @:h = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        @:return "translate(" + (x / h * labelr) + ',' +
           @:(y / h * labelr) + ")";
    @:})
    @:.attr("dy", ".35em")
    @:.attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
        @:// are we past the center?
        @:return (d.endAngle + d.startAngle) / 2 > Math.PI ?
            @:"end" : "start";
    @:})
    @:.text(function (d) { return d.data.name; });
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: You can wrap it into `<text></text>` if you have problems, but overall simply removing `@:` will work

Comment: I tried removing `@:` and it throws an exception. I will try text tags.

Comment: adding `<text></text>` worked great. Thank you!

Comment: @raderick do you care to submit your comment as an answer so I can mark yours as the correct one? I don't want to give credit to someone else for your great suggestion. Thanks

Comment: I left an answer with a really nice link for you to check, it might clarify some of the problems that you might face using razor syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check a great post about Razor syntax here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax

In short, the rule applied here is:

You have a code block - your "if" - and inside of it, code is expected unless:

1. You put an html tag inside. This way, content inside of "if" block will be treated as HTML.
2. You use `<text></text>` tag. This way, content inside `text` tag will be rendered as you put it, without adding any tags or text around it, so for your javascript code it will render the code that you specified.
3. Your text is preceded with `@:` lexeme, which tells razor that content after it should be treated as html/text.

In short, changing your code to this one is what you need:

```
@if(Model.Labels)
{
    <text>
        arcs.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            var c = arc.centroid(d),
                    x = c[0],
                    y = c[1],
                    // pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
                    h = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            return "translate(" + (x / h * labelr) + ',' +
                    (y / h * labelr) + ")";
            })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
            // are we past the center?
            return (d.endAngle + d.startAngle) / 2 > Math.PI ?
                    "end" : "start";
            })
        .text(function (d) { return d.data.name; });
    </text>
}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score 5):

To summarize Razor Syntax:

1- Inline expression
Start with @ symbol to write C# or VB code with Html code. Example:

```
@VariableName
@DateTime.Now // Return the current datetime in Razor
<p> @DateTime.Now </p>
```

2- Multi Statement Code Block:
To write multiple Razor statements enclose them in braces

```
  `@{
     Razor Stmts...
   }`
```

3- Displaying text from a code block (Which is what you are asking for)

You can use `@` or `<text> </text>` to display text depending on your needs. For example:

```
@{
var x = DateTime.Now;
string hello = "Hello Razor!";
<text>The date is:</text> @date <br />
@message                               
}
```